# Using Auth0 to authenticate through custom scenario?

Tags: javascript, java, authentication, passwords, minecraft

I have an idea for a Minecraft plugin which will allow users to log into the website associated with the server without requiring registration, all they would require is their Minecraft username.

I'm trying to find the best way to get [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) to authenticate users through a custom [passwordless](https://github.com/auth0/lock-passwordless) strategy, instead of the default email or SMS which Auth0 provide.

The context which I'll be using this in is as follows:

Minecraft username is entered as their login on the site > Magic link is sent to their text box in-game through a custom plugin and listener > User clicks on the magic link and they are authenticated using Auth0 (JWT token for 30-ish days).

Does this sound possible? or is it wishful thinking.

I know I'll need a custom listener to look for requests from Auth0 and something to return the magic links to the user in-game through a java plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason that it wouldn't be possible, but there are a few factors to take into consideration:

1. Minecraft chat cannot be assumed private and direct. There are chat logs and plugins that can intercept your messages. Passwordless auth is like communicating a one-time-use password, so why would you send it via insecure means?
2. If we assume it's secure, typically it's the responsibility of the user to store the JWTs. If this is a vanilla client, you have no method of storing data on the client, so in the end the server is managing JWTs, which kills the entire reason to use them. Otherwise, why not just have the listener add the player to, say, a cache that expires Players after 30 days of not being accessed?

Other than these two kinks that can be worked out, it sounds like a cool idea. Good luck with it!

Comment: After reading my original post it doesn't make sense really, I've changed the flow to this:


- Enter a command in-game
- Plugin takes the sender's UUID and sends it off to a server I have set up
- Server generates a unique, one-time URL for the player
- The URL is sent to the sender in-game
- Player clicks on the URL which stores a cookie/token in their browser which lasts for ~30 days or so